# Is python asyncio call_soon_threadsafe really thread-safe?

Tags: python, multithreading, python-asyncio

I have saw some code that use `asyncio` as a asynchronous task queue. Maybe like following

```
async def _send_email(address):
    pass

def send_email(address):
    task = asyncio.tasks.ensure_future(_send_email(address))
    task.add_done_callback(callback)

def init_worker(loop):
    asyncio.set_event_loop(loop)
    loop.run_forever()

@app.route("/notify")
def do_jobs():
    # some code
    loop.call_soon_threadsafe(send_email, address)

loop = asyncio.new_event_loop()
worker = threading.Thread(target=init_worker, args=(loop,))
worker.setDaemon(True)
worker.start()

app.run()
```

I read the implementation of `call_soon_threadsafe`. It will append the task to `loop._ready`, the code [here](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Lib/asyncio/base_events.py#L573).

```
self._ready.append(handle)
```

But when the sub thread is executing `_run_once`, and pop the task from `loop._ready`, the code [here](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Lib/asyncio/base_events.py#L1397).

```
handle = self._ready.popleft()
```

I'm not sure if the race condition exists or not. If it does not exist, under what circumstances should use the `queue.Queue`?

Forgive my poor English.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As per https://bugs.python.org/issue15329#msg199368:

> The deque's append(), appendleft(), pop(), popleft(), and len(d) operations are thread-safe in CPython.

And there's info about Queue in the same message:

> > So, is deque a faster replacement for Queue.Queue or not?
>
> Yes, it is faster.  The Queue module itself uses the deque internally.
>     And the Queue is slowed down a bit through locks, function indirection, and additional features such as maxsize, join, and task_done.

`deque` is just a datastructure, but Queue (and asyncio.Queue as well) provide much more, allowing for more flexible control flow.